# Is there any way to increase the text size?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

Using a 55" TV, the size of most UI text is less than 1cm tall.  This is very hard to read sitting 6-7 feet away.

I looked through the options, but I didn't find any obvious way to increase the size of the HUD or text.  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Agreed!  And according to http://www.rtings.com/tv/reviews/by-size/size-to-distance-relationship the optimal distance for 1080p viewing for that size TV is 8 feet away!  (At least it's 5.2ft if you're using a PS4 Pro with 4k viewing, but that font is still REALLY small)

Comment: Bigger text please!

Answer (score 4):

In the Final Fantasy [Update 1.09](http://www.playstationlifestyle.net/2017/04/27/final-fantasy-xv-update-1-09-now-ps4-xbox-one-4-65gb/#/slide/1), the font size has been increased

> Here’s everything Square Enix says was added with update 1.09 today:
>
> ...
>
> Enlarged font sizes for the subtitles and various menu screens
>
> ...

It does not mention exactly how much of an increase, but I am sure it allows a better readability of the text

---

<strike>I have read many reports and complaints on this same issue, however there is currently no way to adjust the font-size in Final Fantasy XV.</strike>

In the meantime, a user on [Final Fantasy XV Forums](https://forum.finalfantasyxv.com/discussion/21435/text-size#latest) suggests

> Until they patch that, try using this: In the Settings menu of the PS4, go to Accessibility and turn on Zoom in. When you want to read the small text, press PS button+Square.

---

In recent discussion, the director states they are looking at tweaking the readability in upcoming updates

[NA Square Enix](http://na.square-enix.com/us/node/6935)

> ... We’re also examining readability tweaks - increasing font size - for certain languages ...